# groovy and spring getting started guide

Tags: spring, groovy

I am looking to learn to gr1oovy with spring framework to access the database. I googled didn't find getting started code for spring and groovy.

Is there similar code for spring and groovy like below url.

[hibernate+groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Hibernate+with+Groovy)

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a web application, the [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) framework is a good choice to start with.

Comment: I am using Grail,looking for standalone program for more understanding. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring4 now can use groovy as the project language, you can really just rewrite any java examples to groovy.

Check out this spring-boot sample:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa